# Refering to properties of a on Angular Component (TypeScript) Class

Tags: angular, typescript, canvas

I'm trying to draw a circle on a canvas in Angular. I do everything fine and kind of understand how the whole thing works. IDE gives no errors, but when i run the code, console says **"this.circleApp is undefined"**. I, few times, am trying to reference properties of circleApp Object where i intend to store most of my App data and logic (like, calculating radians from degrees and thus determining coordinates where my shapes should be at). I'm very new to Angular and TypeScript, and feel like i'm missing something obvious. If someone could tell me what that is or just point me at the right direction and give link to relevant docs, i'd be very thankful.
[illustration of where i think problem is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQvSf.png)

Right now i'm storing just random number as value of "degrees" property, but i want to hook it with input later on.

```
import { ViewChild, Component, OnInit, ElementRef } from "@angular/core";
import { CircleApp } from "./circleApp";
@Component({
  selector: "app-make-circle",
  templateUrl: "./make-circle.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./make-circle.component.css"]
})
export class MakeCircleComponent implements OnInit {
  circleApp: CircleApp = {
    degrees: 3,
    degreesToRadiansFlipped: function(degree) {
      return (-degree * Math.PI) / 180;
    },
    radian: this.circleApp.degreesToRadiansFlipped(this.circleApp.degrees),
    x: Math.cos(this.circleApp.radian * 200 + 500),
    y: Math.sin(this.circleApp.radian * 200 + 500)
  };
  @ViewChild("myCanvas") myCanvas: ElementRef;
  public context: CanvasRenderingContext2D;
  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit() {}
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.context = (this.myCanvas
      .nativeElement as HTMLCanvasElement).getContext("2d");
    this.draw();
  }
  private draw() {
    this.context.beginPath();
    this.context.arc(500, 300, 200, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    this.context.moveTo(500, 300);
    this.context.lineTo(this.circleApp.x, this.circleApp.y);
    this.context.stroke();
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `CircleApp`? What does it look like in `./circleApp`? Can you add that to the post?

Comment: It's the typescript class export where i define what types each property of CircleApp is. In this case, it only says : export class CircleApp {
  degrees: number;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, these lines are the problem (OK, maybe they are just *a* problem):

```
    radian: this.circleApp.degreesToRadiansFlipped(this.circleApp.degrees),
    x: Math.cos(this.circleApp.radian * 200 + 500),
    y: Math.sin(this.circleApp.radian * 200 + 500)
```

`this.circleApp` is referencing the `this.circleApp`, which hasn't yet been created. In simplified form, you're trying to do this:

```js
let foo = { a: "A", b: foo.a + "B" };
```

If you replace the right-side references to `this.circleApp` with some numeric values, or comment them out, the error will disappear.

You simply need to initialize `circleApp` in some other way. If it's a class, just put `this.circleApp = new CircleApp(/* parameters here */)` somewhere early enough in the component's life cycle, like `ngOnInit`.

Comment: Thanks, i moved this.circleApp references to @ngAfterViewInit() and it works fine now.